# Calculating the heat loss on a loudspeaker voice coil

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits

Let's say we have a loudspeaker, the impedance of which is as shown below:

[image]

↑ magnitude in green, phase in red

When calculating the heat loss on the voice coil, should we use "$i^2$ times the **DC resistance of the voice coil**" or "$i^2$ times the **real part of the impedance**"? ← apparently, the two can be very different around the peak of the green curve shown above.

According to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating#cite_note-meier-4) on Joule heating, for alternating current:

> $P_{avg} = U_{rms}I_{rms}cos\phi = I_{rms}^2Re(Z)$
>
> $Re$ means real part, $Z$ is the complex impedance.

So it seems that we should use "$i^2$ times the **real part of the impedance**" in calculating the heat loss.

However, according to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Calculations_and_Equations) on AC power, the real power is derived as:

> $P = |S|cosφ = |I|^2R$
>
> $I$ denotes current in phasor form, with the amplitude as rms.
>
> $R$ denotes resistance of the load.

Therefore, it seems that if we had calculated the heat loss according to the wiki page on Joule heating, it would be the same with the real power. But it's apparent that the power is not only converted to heat, but also the kinetic energy that enables the speaker to generate sound.

So, where did I get it wrong? Should we really calculate the Joule heating with "$i^2$ times the **real part of the impedance**"?

Comment: The graph shows that magnitude (real + imaginary) of the impedance of the coil changes with frequency. The real part of the impedance of the coil  is the resistance of the coil and unless you take the skin effect into consideration that remains independent of frequency.

Comment: @Farcher My understanding: if we calculate the real part of the impedance with the magnitude curve (in green) and the phase curve (in red) in the graph, it will turn out that the real part does vary with frequency. In particular, the real part is significantly larger at the peak of the green curve where the phase angle is zero. Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: I now understand that at resonance the behaves in a purely resistive way and the variation in impedance is due the back emf generated by the moving coil in a magnetic field. Does this article help you? http://sound.whsites.net/articles/speaker-failure.html

Comment: @Farcher Thanks for the article. According to the article, in I^2 times R, "R is the actual resistance of the wire" and it increases linearly with temperature. Since it is the dc resistance that increases linearly with temperature, I guess what the article means by "actual resistance" is dc resistance (not the real part of the impedance). Also, it seems weird to include the increase of the real part of the impedance due to the back emf indo the calculation for heat loss. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A superconductive coil would not heat up, but would have a real part in the impedance. This part represents the energy transfer to the sound. Heating of the coil is caused by the DC resistance of the wire and would not depend on the frequency for the same value of the current. Because all current goes throught the wire, the equivalent circuit is the DC resistance in series with the superconductive coil. So the momentary amount of the heat power is the squared current multiplied by the DC resistance (that depends on the temperature). The amount of the heat energy over time would correspond to the integral of the current.